# export JAVA_HOME not working

Tags: java

The version of Java I have installed on my machine is:

```
java version "1.6.0_24"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.11.11.90) (amazon-62.1.11.11.90.55.amzn1-x86_64)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b12, mixed mode)
```

To set the path of JAVA_HOME, I wrote the following command in the ~/.bashrc file:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/
```

The command `echo $JAVA_HOME` gives the output `/usr/lib/jvm/jre`. I am assuming this is the wrong path, or am I wrong ?

And these are the files I have in the directory `/usr/lib/jvm`

```
java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0.x86_64  
jre
jre-1.6.0  
jre-1.6.0-openjdk.x86_64  
jre-openjdk
```

Comment: Is there a symbolic link back to /usr/lib/jvm/jre ?

Comment: I don't know. How do I find out ?

Comment: did you try source ~/.bashrc ?

Comment: java home should be set to jdk not jre i guess

Comment: I used sudo vi ~/.bashrc

Comment: /usr/lib is a strange place. do you mean /usr/bin ... do "which java" to see where it is at

Answer (score 0):

You should try doing the same using `~/.bash_profile` , and `~/.profile` as well... Then logoff and login, and see if it works using `java --version`

If files don't exist, then create them, add the export, and give them execution permissions using `chmod +x .profile .bash_profile`

Comment: This is what I get after doing all the above steps: 
java version "1.6.0_24"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.11.11.90) (amazon-62.1.11.11.90.55.amzn1-x86_64)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b12, mixed mode)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that maybe default-java is a symbolic link to all versions of java installed on your machine. Have you tried setting it to a specific java jdk bin?

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0.x86_64/
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your `javac` program path using:

```
whereis javac
```

In debian based distributions use

```
sudo update-alternatives --display javac
```

To find out where your `javac` program resides, also (if you have several jdk's installed) `update-alternatives` lets you change the default javac

Update your `JAVA_HOME` in your `~/.bashrc` and then type: `source ~/.bashrc`, then print again `echo $JAVA_HOME`, the change should apply immediately